# Unable to get data as tabular format

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I've written a script in vba using IE to get the data from a webpage. The data are not stored within any table, I meant there is no `table`,`tr` or `td` tag. However, they look like to be in a tabular format. You can see the below image for clarity.

What I've tried so far can get the data in a single line like:

```
$4,085  
$1,620
$1,435  
$35
$1,125  
$905
```

How I wish to get them is like:

```
$4,085  $1,620
$1,435  $35
$1,125  $905
```

In other languages there is an option for `list comprehension` using which I can handle it in a single line of code but in case of vba I get stuck.

`html elements` within which the data are (It's just a chunk of the whole):

```
<ul id="tco_detail_data">
    <li>
        <ul class="list-title">
            <li class="first">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Year 1</li>
            <li>Year 2</li>
            <li>Year 3</li>
            <li>Year 4</li>
            <li>Year 5</li>
            <li class="last">5 Yr Total</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <hr class="loose-dotted">


    <li class="first">
        <ul class="first">
            <li class="first">Depreciation</li>
                        <li>$4,085</li>
                        <li>$1,620</li>
                        <li>$1,425</li>
                        <li>$1,263</li>
                        <li>$1,133</li>
                    <li class="last">$9,526</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The data look like in that page:

[image]

This is what I've attempted so far:

```
Sub Get_Information()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "https://www.edmunds.com/ford/escape/2017/cost-to-own/?zip=43215"
        While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .Document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") 'waiting for the items to be available

    For Each post In HTML.getElementById("tco_detail_data").getElementsByTagName("li")
        Debug.Print post.innerText
    Next post
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library to execute the above script:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: is this really something that needs to be automated? how often does this data need to be pulled?

Comment: I may not need to pull them at all but I do need to know how to accomplish the task the way I've asked @ashleedawg. Thanks.

Comment: I can't even find the page you're looking at, using the link in your code, so it's impossible to even try to help,  There is no "blanket answer", every web page is different.

Comment: Glad to accept it @ashleedawg. That what is difficult to solve should be downvoted. There is nothing wrong with that link. I have checked with several ip's. Btw, which portion of my question is unclear and how often this has been asked? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works using CSS selector. Updated to remove explicit wait.

The selector is:

```
#tco_detail_data > li
```

Which is the `li` within id of `tco_detail_data`

Which looks like the following sample results from webpage using CSS query

[image: CSS query]

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Get_Information()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://www.edmunds.com/ford/escape/2017/cost-to-own/?zip=43215"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With
    Dim a As Object, exitTime As Date
    exitTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    Do
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next
        Set a = IE.document.querySelectorAll("#tco_detail_data")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Now > exitTime Then Exit Do
    Loop While a Is Nothing

    If a Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim resultsNodeList As Object, i As Long, arr() As String
    Set resultsNodeList = HTML.querySelectorAll("#tco_detail_data > li")

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 0 To 9
            arr = Split(resultsNodeList(i).innerText, Chr$(10))
            .Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        Next
    End With

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

---

**Result in sheet**

[image: Result]

---

**Additional info:**

The array part is because resultsNodeList(i).innerText returns as a "stacked string" - i.e. with line breaks in between; See image below. I split on those, to produce an array, which I then write out to the sheet. The array is 0 based, so I have to add 1 to be able to populate the range properly.

[image: unsplit strings]

Comment: Good job! (The page doesn't even want to fullly load for me.)

Comment: It's just awesomeeeeeee @QHarr!! I'm familiar with setectors. Could you help me understand the array portion? I'm little behind. Provided +1. Gonna accept it when time is right. Thanks.

Comment: Year1 Year2 etc actually returns as a "stacked string" - i.e. with line breaks in between. I split on that character to produce an array which I then write out to the sheet. The array is 0 based so I have to add 1 to be able to populate range properly. Year1Year etc being resultsNodeList(i).innerText

Comment: Got rid of never ending loop. You are really the gem @QHarr.

Comment: I saw you had removed the time bit and thought I had better do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what QHarr has already shown, there is another way the same goal can be achieved:

```
Sub Get_Information()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object, oitem As Object
    Dim R&, C&, B As Boolean

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "https://www.edmunds.com/ford/escape/2017/cost-to-own/?zip=43215"
        Do While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set HTML = .Document
    End With

    ''no hardcoded delay is required. The following line should take care of that

    Do: Set oitem = HTML.getElementById("tco_detail_data"): DoEvents: Loop While oitem Is Nothing

    For Each posts In oitem.getElementsByTagName("li")
        C = 1: B = False

        For Each post In posts.getElementsByTagName("li")
            Cells(R + 1, C).Value = post.innerText
            C = C + 1: B = True
        Next post

        If B Then R = R + 1
    Next posts
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```